# what are these outputs in terminal while installing/upgrading jdk

Tags: java, openjdk, jdk

I've been installing jdk

i have more than single problem

1.in 1st line when i try to set alternative of java it said java is already managed what does this mean

2.why i have to type java1, javac1. couldn't i type java2, javac2

3.when i try to set alternate java it says i have 3 different priority status in which the top two are same and difference between auto mode and manual mode.

4.And in the last line i choose java2. will it make any difference. am i free to choose any number

```
neeraj@dodo:/$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/javac 1
[sudo] password for neeraj: 
update-alternatives: error: alternative link /usr/bin/java is already managed by java
neeraj@dodo:/$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/java 1
neeraj@dodo:/$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/javaws 1
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/javaws to provide /usr/bin/javaws (javaws) in auto mode
neeraj@dodo:/$ sudo update-alternatives --config javac
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for javac
neeraj@dodo:/$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java)

Selection Path Priority Status

* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/java                1         manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode
neeraj@dodo:/$ sudo update-alternatives --config javaws
There is only one alternative in link group javaws (providing /usr/bin/javaws): /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/javaws
Nothing to configure.
neeraj@dodo:/$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b15, mixed mode)
neeraj@dodo:/$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/java 1
[sudo] password for neeraj: 
neeraj@dodo:/$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_72/bin/java 2
```

Comment: It's telling you that the link for a `javac` alternative should be `/usr/bin/javac` rather than `/usr/bin/java` (which is already reserved for `java` alternatives)

Comment: And what about problem no 3 and 4 thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I follow this [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) for installing Oracle/Sun JDK and it works fine for me.

In one instance i need to manually update my JAVA_HOME in /etc/environment(by editing it)

```
JAVA_HOME=/path-to-java-before bin directory
export $JAVA_HOME
source /etc/environment
```

Hope this works.

Comment: I know about ppa method but I want to know what is happening behind this method that's why I'm doing this manually